# Can't install scipy to Raspberry pi 4 (raspbian)

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am trying to install the `scipy` library with `python3 -m pip install --user --no-use-pep517 scipy` but I am receiving the following error:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for scipy
  Running setup.py clean for scipy
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-spokr6ic/scipy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-spokr6ic/scipy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-spokr6ic/scipy
```

I am using that code to install because `pip3 install scipy` is giving me this error:

```
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scipy
Failed to build scipy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scipy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Python == 3.7.3

PS:The complete traceback is 414 lines. I don't know if I should include here.

Comment: FYI, RPi-specific support can be found at our sister site [raspberrypi.se]

Comment: (Incidentally, `nix run --argstr system aarch64-linux '((import <nixpkgs> {}).python3.withPackages (p: [p.scipy]))' -c python3` actually brings up a working Python repl with scipy available, when run on a system that has Nix installed and can execute aarch64 binaries; if you have a stock 32-bit Raspian, not so much on either criteria, but it's certainly *possible* to get there on a Pi).

Comment: I also encountered same error when I tried to install dask-ml. I was able to install dask but dask-ml got stuck here. Looking for a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y python3-scipy
```